# NullPointerException on getter

Tags: java, arrays, oop, nullpointerexception, getter

I am working on a class final. It is supposed to be a "Media Library" to stores information about a persons media(DVDs, games etc.) among other things it's supposed to take in new media items, store them to an array and display them when prompted. It does all of those but when it displays it has a NullPointerException on the getters even though it is executing it how I intended.

```
public class MediaItem {
private String title;
private String format;
private boolean onLoan;
private String loanedTo;
private String dateLoaned;

public MediaItem(){
    title = null;
    format = null;
    onLoan = false;
    loanedTo = null;
    dateLoaned = null;

}

public MediaItem(String title, String format){
    this.title = title;
    this.format = format;
    onLoan = false;

}
```

Above are the fields and constructors for the class that makes the "MediaItems" as we were told to call them

Below, parts of another class, that is the library itself. One array for storing the media items and one for printing out the list. Also the add method and how I have been adding them to the array.

```
private MediaItem[] items = new MediaItem[100];
private String[] listOfItems = new String[100];
private int numberOfItems = 0;  

public void addNewItem(String title, String format){
    MediaItem item = new MediaItem(title, format);
    items[numberOfItems] = item;
    numberOfItems++;
}
```

And here is the part I am having problems with

```
    public void listAllItems(){
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        System.out.println(items[i].getTitle());
    }   
    }
```

This isn't what its supposed to do, but my current problem is that it does print out the entire list of items but also gives a NullPointerException and I dont know why. The getter that is being called is a basic eclipse generated getter

```
    public String getTitle() {
    return title;
    }
```

This is a Java I coarse so I'm new so please be gentle. I believe that is all the relevant parts so any help is appreciated!

Comment: `items[i]` is certainly null for a certain value of `i`. If you don't call `addNewItem` 100 times, there will always be a NPE with this line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items.length` will always be the length of the entire array (100 in your case), nomatter how many items you have actually added. Try it like this:

```
public void listAllItems(){
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++){
    System.out.println(items[i].getTitle());
  }   
}
```

The problem in your case is not the getter itself but trying to call the `getTitle()` method on `null`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I cant't believe I didn't notice that and could swear I tried it that way before to no avail, the method above it has exactly that, but its true that fresh eyes can make a world of difference. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You do have 100 places reserved but I suspect that not all the places are occupied. This causes the NullPointerException when accessing properties of these element.

You can use below method to get all non-null elements from the array:

```
public void listAllItems(){
  int i = 0;
  while (i < numberOfItems){
    if (items[i] != null) // Null check
      System.out.println(items[i].getTitle());
    i+=1;
  }   
}
```

Or using the same 'for' loop with just the null check should also suffice:

```
public void listAllItems(){
   for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    if (items[i] != null)
      System.out.println(items[i].getTitle());
   }     
}
```